# Fetch Followers from Twitter Account

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

```
- (IBAction)getTwitterContact:(id)sender
{
     ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    // Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    // let's request access and fetch the accounts

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)

   //[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)

    {
                                // check that the user granted us access and there were no errors (such as no accounts added on the users device)
                                if (granted && !error) {
                                    NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                                    if ([accountsArray count] > 1) {
                                        // a user may have one or more accounts added to their device
                                        // you need to either show a prompt or a separate view to have a user select the account(s) you need to get the followers and friends for
                                    } else {
                                        [self getTwitterFriendsForAccount:[accountsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    // handle error (show alert with information that the user has not granted your app access, etc.)
                                }
                            }];  
}

-(void)getTwitterFriendsForAccount:(ACAccount*)account
{
    // In this case I am creating a dictionary for the account
    // Add the account screen name
    NSMutableDictionary *accountDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:account.username, @"screen_name", nil];
    // Add the user id (I needed it in my case, but it's not necessary for doing the requests)
    [accountDictionary setObject:[[[account dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"properties"]] objectForKey:@"properties"] objectForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"user_id"];
    // Setup the URL, as you can see it's just Twitter's own API url scheme. In this case we want to receive it in JSON
    NSURL *followingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json"];
    // Pass in the parameters (basically '.ids.json?screen_name=[screen_name]')
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:account.username, @"screen_name", nil];
    // Setup the request

    //TWRequest *twitterRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:followingURL parameters:parametersrequestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];



    SLRequest *aRequest  = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                        URL:followingURL
                                                 parameters:parameters];


    // This is important! Set the account for the request so we can do an authenticated request. Without this you cannot get the followers for private accounts and Twitter may also return an error if you're doing too many requests
    [aRequest setAccount:account];
    // Perform the request for Twitter friends
    [aRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // deal with any errors - keep in mind, though you may receive a valid response that contains an error, so you may want to look at the response and ensure no 'error:' key is present in the dictionary
        }
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        // Convert the response into a dictionary
        NSDictionary *twitterFriends = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&jsonError];
        // Grab the Ids that Twitter returned and add them to the dictionary we created earlier
        [accountDictionary setObject:[twitterFriends objectForKey:@"ids"] forKey:@"friends_ids"];
        NSLog(@"%@", accountDictionary);
    }];
}
```

i have used this code to get the twitter followers lsit but crash my app 
error log is

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'**

myarray is nil thats why this error comes but i dont know. why this is nill..

whre may i go wrong help me to do this.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Hey You're checking for more than one account, but you're not checking whether there is at least one account.

So, in place of the code below:

```
if ([accountsArray count] > 1) {
    // a user may have one or more accounts added to their device
    // you need to either show a prompt or a separate view to have a user select the account(s) you need to get the followers and friends for
} else {
    [self getTwitterFriendsForAccount:[accountsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

try this:

```
if ([accountsArray count] > 1) {
    // a user may have one or more accounts added to their device
    // you need to either show a prompt or a separate view to have a user select the account(s) you need to get the followers and friends for
} else if([accountsArray count] == 1) {
    [self getTwitterFriendsForAccount:[accountsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
} else {
    // There is no account setup in settings.
    // Show message to go settings and setup an account for twitter.
}
```

And you should also try Twitter-API 1.1, instead of API-1.0, because API 1.0 is deprecated now.

So use:            https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json

in place of:       https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json

```
// Prepare to fetch available Twitter accounts in the device settings
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
```

**Updated** : Here is the code that's working for me.

```
// Fetch accounts available locally
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        // Check if the users has setup at least one Twitter account
        if (accounts.count > 0) {

        } else {

        }
    } else {
        // Permission Denied
    }
}];
```

Comment: i think this is not solution my accountarray not contain any value thats why this error comes...

Comment: And I am saying the same thing, Dude. I just put a check.

Comment: -(void)getTwitterFriendsForAccount:(ACAccount*)account this method not being called..

Comment: Go to the iOS-device settings, and in 'Twitter' section setup an account, then there will be at-least one entry in your 'accountarray'.

Comment: i have alredy done that but not get any thing in array.

Comment: Yes. How can it be, if you have no account in the device-settings. Because twitter api on iOS work on the accounts setup in settings for twitter. If there is no account, your 'accountarray' will be empty and that's why there is 'NSRangeException' occurs.

Comment: so how may i  fill this array

Comment: I've added the code to the answer, that I've used to implement the task. First I fetch all accounts, present them to user to select one and then verify account credential. If verified, do whatever you need to do.